# FIle is not uploading to another directory in same server.?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to upload file to an directory of another outside of my word-press directory.

Here is my HTML

```
<form>
<div class="form-group  upload-btn-wrapper2">
<span id="">Member Passport - Front</span>
<input required="" type="file" dir="rtl" name="member_passport_front_copy_names" id="member_passport_front_copy_names" class="form-control valid" for="UAE citizen" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
</div>

</form>
```

Here is my AJAX Function.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                jQuery('body').on('change', '#member_passport_front_copy_names', function (evt) {

                         var data = new FormData(this.form);
                          var data = new FormData();
        var files = jQuery('#member_passport_front_copy_names')[0].files[0];
        data.append('file',files);
                         jQuery.ajax({
                             url: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cms_filesubmit',
                             type: "POST",
                             data: data,
                            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                            contentType: false,
                             processData: false,
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: "html",
                             success: function (response) {
                                  console.log(response);

                             },
                             error: function (response) { 
                             alert("something went wrong");
                             }
                         });


            });
                });
```

Here is my PHP function to upload file to directory

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cms_filesubmit', 'cms_filesubmit' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cms_filesubmit', 'cms_filesubmit' );

function cms_filesubmit(){

$target_dir = "http://sajaya.ae/himmah/app/webroot/img/user_upload/";

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"http://sajaya.ae/himmah/app/webroot/img/user_upload/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
}
```

When ever i change or upload file it give in response Success but file not get uploaded to directory.

Comment: Most likely [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) didn't work properly. Try to check the result of this function.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` does not work with HTTP URLs, you need to specify a file system path. (If you are not aware of the difference between the two, go read up on that first of all.)

Comment: @misorude should is use ../../../../ for that

Comment: Either that, or the complete local file system path from the server root directory.

Comment: @misorude Thanks alot your saved my life i had to use $_SERVER to get root directory. I would like to post it as answer so i can thumb you up. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file` does not work with HTTP URLs – you need to specify a file system path for the destination.

Either relative to the current working directory of your script, or as a full absolute path from the server file system’s root directory.